# How to remove invalid ASCII code in lengthy document..specifics please

Tags: txt

To start with, not familiar with code at all. I was asked to convert a Word doc to txt, then was told it couldn't be more than 80 characters across. Did that. Now the system has given me over 1000 different versions of this error code "Line Number: 2 In circular.txt: found an invalid ASCII code (128). How do I get rid of the "invalid ASCII codes"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this and hence, no easy answer Cathy sorry.  In Windows one could use Excel as in this example from Google https://www.lifewire.com/remove-ascii-character-127-in-excel-3123799.  In Unix one could use any number of tools, `sed` jumping to my mind.  However, the scope of this question is a little too broad and what you're probably trying to do a little too narrow to get a good answer from stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

They assigned the wrong person to task this to..lol I have a 60+ page txt doc, has to be only 80 characters across, and 700+ "Invalid ascii codes" Mostly 128, 156, 157, 226. With the exception of going line by line, is there a way to convert it again with a program that will remove invalid ascii to begin with? Or with my txt, is there a program that will remove? Or at least highlight, so I know what they are?